# Generate last num of array and append to list for num of times python

Tags: python, logic

I have a function which will do the process of generating a number for me:

```
gnrt(num)
```

when I input that `num` to gnrt func
it will return me a new number and that new number will generate a new number and it will add to the list and the new numbers all are added to list.

for ex, I have a number 654

I want to process that number and add to list

```
lst=[654]
```

then do process for `654` and it will generate for ex
`190`

```
lst=[654,190]
```

Do this process for number of times

Last example

```
lst=[23]
gnrt(last item of list)
out:16

lst=[23,16]

gnrt(last item of list)
out:621

lst=[23,16,621]

#I want to do it while condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
current_time = 0
number_of_times = 5
list = [23]
while current_time < number_of_times:
    # The -1 index means we get the last element in list
    x = gnrt(list[-1])
    list.append(x)
```

Comment: my friend it will gnrt for last item of list each time

Comment: Dear @jacky, in the example you gave it adds to the end of the list. Do you want to add to the beginning?

Comment: Maybe you mean that you want to activate grnt on the last item of the list?

Comment: no no .. each time it will append to last item .. and the next loop it will generate for last item of list... then append to list

Comment: Edited accordingly - is that helpful for you? Write more explanation elsewise

Comment: I think it will solve my problem ❤❤❤❤.. when Iam inform .of computer i will test the code .. thanks slot... I will inform you later... many thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
for i in range(number_of_times):
      lst.append(gnrt(lst[-1]))
```

`number_of_times` should be a int (Ex `number_of_times = 5`). You need to have first number in `lst`(Ex  `lst = [5]`) or just append it(`lst.append(number)`).

Comment: They say "I want to do it while condition". Perhaps something like [Collatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), so until they arrived at 1.